# Пропуск значений в регулярке

Tags: php

Есть вот такой вот такая регулярка для получения значений между

```
<group id="1"  code="[0-9]" code2="[0-9]">(.*?)<\/group>
```

Спарсить пытаюсь значения между group. В code, code2 какие то цифры разной длинны.
Но почему то ни чего не парситься (preg_match)

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, исходный текст, который вы пытаетесь обработать.

Comment: `<group id="1"  code="43" code2="2634463">2134141551<\/group>`

Comment: `<group id="1"  code="[0-9]`**+**`" code2="[0-9]`**+**`">(.*?)<\/group>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Регуляркам обязательно нужно указывать длину символьных классов, в вашем примере code/code2 могут быть только цифрами, потому что у них (по умолчанию) указана длина в один символ. Таким образом:

```
[0-9] -> [0-9]+ -> \d+
```

И еще. Паттерн

```
(.*?)
```

в данном контексте идентичен паттерну

```
(.*)
```

и еще не забываем, что экранирующий слэш должен заэкранировать сам себя, чтобы присутствовать в качестве обычного символа:

```
<\/group> -> <\\/group>
```

*(у меня, почему-то, пых требовал три обратных слэша для совпадения, сейчас мне некогда лезть так глубоко).*

Таким образом, нужный вам паттерн будет таким:

```
#<group id="1"  code="\d+" code2="\d+">(.*)<\\/group>#
```

Хотя лучше - таким:

```
#<group\s+id="1"\s+code="\d+"\s+code2="\d+">(.*)<\\/group>#
```

А если у вас абсолютно точно верные данные и значения атрибутов вам не нужны, то и таким:

```
#<group[^>]*>(.*)<\\/group>#
```

я настоятельно рекомендую внимательно прочесть раздел документации про регулярки, это не та  тема, на которой получится "срезать".

**Что произошло в примерах наверху:**

В регулярных выражениях есть такие вещи, как предопределенные символьные классы и квантификаторы, которые позволяют сильно упростить жизнь:

```
классы:
\d = [0-9]
\w = [a-zA-Z0-9] (в пхп еще и подчерки, насколько помню)
\s - все пробельные символы
\D, \W, \S - все символы, кроме \d, \w и \s соответственно

квантификаторы:
{2,4} - символ/подмаска встретится от двух до четырех раз
{0,} - символ/подмаска встретится от нуля до бесконечности раз
* = {0,}
+ = {1,}
? = {0,1}
{квантификатор}? - переключение режима жадности квантификатора. Жадный квантификатор заставит совпасть с максимально длинной возможной строкой, не жадный совпадет с наименее длинной возможной строкой. Здесь нас это вообще не интересует, потому что тег кончается однозначно.
```

Таким образом, в вышепривеенном паттерне переключался режим жадности подмаски (некритично), был использован полный синтаксис символьных классов (некритично) и не была указана длительность символьных классов (что и повлекло несовпадение).

P.S. Есть еще полезные символьные классы [:alpha:] и [:alnum:] (и не только), но я не уверен на сто процентов, что они совпадают только с алфавитом и цифрами. Примерно для этого и нужно прочитать гигабайт документации.